# enable one uicontrol by another uicontrol MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, uicontrol

I have 2 edittext uicontrol. I want to enable the second if the first input ensures the condition. However, I encounter with the error 'Reference to non-existing field'. My code is below:

```
 % xadet is a number input
 S.eth_xadet = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'String','1',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'BackgroundColor','w',...
    'Position',[200 68 30 18],...
    'callback',{@eth_x_adet_enable,S});

% xaralik is a number input
S.eth_xaralik = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'enable','off',...
    'String','0',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'Position',[240 68 50 18]);

function [] = eth_x_adet_enable(varargin)

S = varargin{3}

x_adet = str2double(get(S.eth_xadet,{'String'}));

if x_adet > 1 % if input is bigger than 1, enable xaralik
    set(S.eth_xaralik,'enable','on',...
        'BackgroundColor','w');
end
```

Comment: remove `{}` in `x_adet = str2double(get(S.eth_xadet,{'String'}))` ? btw, does Matlab tell you the error appears in which line?

Comment: Whether to remove {} is not my problem. I took x_adet as an input in the same script with the same line of code. Also, Matlab does not tell where the problem is. Instead, it indicates that "Reference to non-existing field 'S.eth_xadet' ".

Comment: You'd get more help if you'd post executable code of a minimal example reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callbacks should be defined after uicontrols are defined.

```
 % xadet is a number input
 S.eth_xadet = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'String','1',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'BackgroundColor','w',...
    'Position',[200 68 30 18]);

% xaralik is a number input
S.eth_xaralik = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'enable','off',...
    'String','0',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'Position',[240 68 50 18]);

% Here this part solves the problem.
set(S.eth_xadet,'callback',{@eth_x_adet_enable,S})

function [] = eth_x_adet_enable(varargin)

S = varargin{3}

x_adet = str2double(get(S.eth_xadet,{'String'}));

if x_adet > 1 % if input is bigger than 1, enable xaralik
    set(S.eth_xaralik,'enable','on',...
        'BackgroundColor','w');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error actually occurs because of this line:

```
S = varargin{3}
```

You already provide `S` as an input argument to the function in the callback definition so there is no need to retrieve it again.

If you remove that line it works fine. As @thewaywewalk mentioned you should provide a minimal example of the whole code you use to get the error.

Alternatively, if you display `varargin` in the edit box callback, you will see that `varargin{1}` is actually the handles to `eth_xadet` so you could use

```
P = varargin{1}      
x_adet = str2double(get(P,'String'));
```

and it would work fine as well.

Anyhow, I simply created a new function and added a figure whose handles is `S.ph_agac` and it works ok:

```
function EnableEdit(~)

clc
clear

S.ph_agac = figure;
% xadet is a number input
S.eth_xadet = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'String','1',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'BackgroundColor','w',...
    'Position',[200 68 30 18],...
    'callback',{@eth_x_adet_enable,S});

% xaralik is a number input
S.eth_xaralik = uicontrol(S.ph_agac,'Style','edit',...
    'enable','off',...
    'String','0',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'Position',[240 68 50 18]);


    function [] = eth_x_adet_enable(varargin)
%// =================
%// Note I removed the S = varargin{3} line
%// =================
        x_adet = str2double(get(S.eth_xadet,'String'));

        if x_adet > 1 % if input is bigger than 1, enable xaralik
            set(S.eth_xaralik,'enable','on',...
                'BackgroundColor','w');
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: I have the same code you wrote above. The only difference is that 'S' is blue in yours whereas black in mine